# Converting an issue to a string

Tags: rebol, rebol3

In Rebol 2 you can convert an `issue` to a `string` with a simple `to string!`
For example,

```
>> to string! #12345-12345  
== "12345-12345"
```

In Rebol 3 the behaviour is different.
For example,

```
>> to string! #12345-12345  
== "#12345-12345"
```

My current solution is,

```
remove to string! #12345-12345  
== "12345-12345"
```

But I don't like this solution as it makes an assumption of what the string representation will be. Is there a better way of retrieving the value from an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R3, the `issue!` type [has been changed to a word subtype](http://www.rebol.net/r3blogs/0108.html) (i.e. a member of the `any-word!` typeset):

```
>> any-word? #12345-12345
== true
```

So your question can be rephrased as: how to obtain the canonical spelling of any word type?

The approach I'd like to suggest is to convert to a plain `word!` first, and then convert that to a string:

```
>> form to word! #12345-12345
== "12345-12345"
```